# who is responsible as international court to solve economic conflicts between countries and is it obligatory?

Tags: law

you know turkey was one of the 7members of F-35 joint strike fighter program..its engine is being manufactured in turkey.turkish government made all legal obligations to program and paid 35 billion dollars to budget pool so far but american congress decided to end delivery of 200fighters to turkey illegally by trump's decision last week..
so i heard a news on cnn turk this evening that turkey minister of defence is going to moscow to negotiate agreed terms to buy 300 SU-57 stealth fighter from sukoi instead next month..i think this will be important step of turkey's way to waited exit from NATO after S400 agreement of last year..it is called 'bricst-it" in turkey at the moment..it is possible to join to BRICS instead of NATO&EU for turkey..but in continue of news,there will be a government decision of turkey to prosecute united states government worth 1,8 trillion dollars sum plus with all turkey's army lost from F-35 program and legal compensations and interest rate of 20 years..ok here is my question..which international court may look at this case and is decision obligatory?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about international law, not economics.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there is no "general" international court for economic affairs.
The ICJ (Interntaional Court of Justice) is the judicial organ of the UN, and it in fact decided few cases with economic background, but usually in the context of other questions of international law.
The closest to what you are looking for is probably WTO dispute settlement system, which is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispute_settlement_in_the_WTO
In theory, it is for WTO members only, but in practice, 96 % of global trade is covered under WTO.

Other possible court is the International Court of Arbitration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Court_of_Arbitration
It has no clearly defined jurisdiction, instead, the parties must agree to bring the case to it, but it is becoming increasingly popular.

Last, but not least, an ad hoc panel can be established specially for given dispute.